# 480x320 display HDMI - blank after boot

Tags: hdmi, display, config.txt

I am trying to get to work mini HDMI chinese 480x320 display.
I want to display only console output, and that resolution is good enough for it.
Display is known to be ok, during boot it shows good resolution (the fonts are readable!), BUT after the initial "4 raspberries at the top" booting sequence, display goes blank and does not show anything.

the /boot/config.txt  has following to enable this resolution

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 480 320 60 6 0 0 0
```

i also tried putting a "hdmi_mode=1" - did not help "hdmi_force_hotplug=1" - did not help, with also randomly uncommenting those commands on or off. Any other resolution causes display to show too small font to be readable - and by small i mean blurry, not native.

Using Pi zero 2 W with Raspbian buster, updated.

Comment: maybe the `quiet`  argument is in the kernel command line  ... https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/kernel-command-line.7.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone will wonder (i bet it will be me in future)
i commented dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d

----->

#dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d

now i see nice terminal output.
It was a pure guesswork after many trials.
Thanks for at least trying to help Milliways!

Comment: Frankly this should have been blindingly obvious - particularly if you had read the documentation as these settings only apply to fkms. Your question stated Buster which does not use kms (although I believe it was available for testing).

Comment: yeah, i guess i have problem remembering those stupid version names, that all start with same letter. A number like 1, 2, 3 would be much better (windows 10, windows 11...), oh well.